# What am I doing wrong with this permission error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using the Google Sheets API v4 with Node.js.

When using the endpoint `spreadsheets.values.update`, I get the following error back:

> You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you need to edit.

Background info and previous troubleshooting:

- I use a Google Service Account with JSON credentials.
- I can successfully use the `spreadsheets.values.get` endpoint with the same credentials. Thus, all the authorization setup is working.
- The service account user has edit permissions on the Google Spreadsheet.
- **The spreadsheet has no protected cells.**
- Using the "Try this API" functionality of [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) works. Of course here I get a prompt to authorize. In this case, I authorize with my personal user account (which also has access to the spreadsheet).
- I have also tried this with a newly created service account as well as a copy of the Google Spreadsheet. Same error.

Comment: Who is making calls to spreadsheets.values.update, your service account or your personal account? They are not the same so if it works on service accounts, it doesn't mean that your personal user account has access to it too.

Comment: It's the service account. I understand there is a difference.
I tested the "Try this API" with my personal account since I can't login/authenticate with the service account at this point.

In my node.js code I am authenticating with the service account.

Comment: That error message **reallllly** makes it seem like there are protected cells in the range that you're editing. Can you confirm that this issue exists on a 100% "clean" sheet? I.e., create a sheet, share it with the service account, and then use your code. What happens then?

Comment: Please share the output of this query (using the appropriate spreadsheet id): https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get?fields=sheets%252FprotectedRanges

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you so much for these valuable troubleshooting tips. I found the issue: With my API call I was accidentally writing to another range, which was in fact set to protected.